# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\AppServ\www\text.php on line 11

Tags: php, syntax-error, echo

I am new to PHP and have a question about it.

```
<?php

    echo "Do you like it?";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ";

?>
```

When I try to load this script in my browser, I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\AppServ\www\text.php on line 11

Lline 11 is

```
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please use a more relevant title.

Comment: You cannot use literal quotes in a string, of the same type that were used to quote the string, without escaping them. I highly recommend you read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) from start to finish and keep reading it until you understand everything it is saying.

Comment: Sure next time i will put proper title

Answer (score 6):

The issue is the inner quotes (`"`) around the style data are ending the string. Either use a single quote `'` (this way PHP will look for another single quote to represent the end of the string):

```
echo 'My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ';
```

Or escape the double quotes in the string:

```
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style=\"text-align:center;\">Karthic</div></i></b>";
```

This tells PHP to ignore them when parsing the code (and instead place them INSIDE the string itself).

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes when printing HTML

```
echo 'My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ';
```

Instead of

```
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ";
```

You were cutting off the HTML string, so it was erroring out.

Comment: Or escape your `"` with slashes.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference really, I like single quotes. Either way, both of our answers would do the job :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't do

```
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style="text-align:center;">Karthic</div></i></b> ";
```

because there is 2 double quote one after echo one after style

you should then do

```
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style=\"text-align:center;\">Karthic</div></i></b> ";
```

but most of all of this ; you dont need to do echo for HTML code like this.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You will have to escape any double quotes that are contained within double quotes. You escape double quotes using the backslash character.

```
<?php
echo "Do you like it?";
echo "<br>";
echo "My name is:<b><i><div style=\"text-align:center;\">Karthic</div></i></b> ";
?>
```

You should also put the bold and italic tags within the div instead of outside of it.